# Auto-save node in database

Tags: 7, entities, media

I searched a lot for auto-save functionality which will direclty save in to db, but I am not getting anything like what I want, so I am posting my query, any help is very appreciate.

**The requirement is like after every 1-min entire node should be save in db.**

**The problem I am facing:**  For content type(Story) has many field collection(Unlimited), Image field. So how to auto-save this in db, as I am not understanding how to track how many field collection content added, how many deleted base etc. so how to save this.

For this requirement I have done like this:

### - Calling Ajax after every 1 min and pass form by serialize.

```
setInterval(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: Drupal.settings.basePath + '?q=ajax/autosave',
            data: jQuery('.content .node-form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            success: function (returnData) {
            }
        });
   }, 60000);
```

### - Accept post data, loading node and save the node.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_menu()
 *  
 */
function autosave_menu() {
    $items['ajax/autosave'] = array(
        'title' => 'Autosave',
        'description' => 'Autosave',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('save_node_automatically'),
        'access callback' => TRUE
    );
    return $items;
}

function save_node_automatically($form, &$form_state) {
    $node = node_load(2);

    $bundle_name = $node->type;
// Get fields array
    $field_instance = field_info_instances('node', $bundle_name);

    try {
        $node->title = $form_state['input']['title'];
        $node->body = $form_state['input']['body'];
        $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = $form_state['input']['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'];
        $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['summary'] = $form_state['input']['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['summary'];
        $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['input']['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

        // Traverse from fields
        foreach ($field_instance as $field_name => $field_details) {

            // Check field Type
            $field_type = $field_details['display']['default']['module'];
            switch ($field_type) {
                case 'entityreference':
                    if ($form_state['input'][$field_name]['und'] != '_none' && $form_state['input'][$field_name]['und'] != '') {
                        $node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = $form_state['input'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE];
                    } else {
                        $node->{$field_name} = array();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'taxonomy':
                    if ($form_state['input'][$field_name]['und'] != '_none') {
                        $node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = $form_state['input'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE];
                    } else {
                        $node->{$field_name} = array();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'list':
                    if ($form_state['input'][$field_name]['und'] != '') {
                        $node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['input'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE];
                    }
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    if ($form_state['input'][$field_name]['und'][0]['value'] != '') {
                        $node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['input'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
                    }
                    break;
                case 'field_collection':
                /**
                 *  Field Collection code
                 * 
                 */
            }
        }
        $node->revision = FALSE;
        node_save($node);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you had a look at [Autosave](https://www.drupal.org/project/autosave) module. The module auto save the node in db.

Comment: Yes Yogesh I checked that one also, it is not saving in db.

Comment: @vijay why do you think it does not save to the database? the autosave_save() function (line 387 of http://cgit.drupalcode.org/autosave/tree/autosave.module) performs a `db_merge()` which stores the form to the database.